# Can multiple thread perform Single task, So that task gets done quickly ? in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task, it consumes lots of seconds to complete. So I want to know whether using the multithreading concept in Java, can I use multiple threads to perform that single task, so that my task would get done quickly.

Here is my Example. Thread Class:

```
public class ThreadImpl implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String value="a";

        for (int i = 0; i < 2147483646; i++) {
            value = value + "b";
        }
        System.out.println("thread task completed " + value);
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadImpl());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

I want to understand, is it really possible to create multiple threads and execute that task `public void run()` alone simultaneously? If yes, how to achieve this?

Comment: What does "alone simultaneously" mean?

Comment: Where is 'a' of parameter?

Comment: This is a very complex question. Does the task do input/output?  Does the task do only computation that does not require accessing external resources?  Does each step in the task depend on previous results?  Your example does no I/O except once at the end, so you could run as many instances as you have hardware cores. 8 cores would give an 8x speedup.  If the task does a lot of I/O or has sequential dependencies you might not get a big speedup.  There's no single answer to this question.

Comment: I meant, multiple thread executing at the same time to perform that task @tgdavies

Comment: @JimGarrison There is no I/O. I just need to execute that task alone with multiple threads together inorder to reduce exeuction time.

Comment: Then if you can partition the data being processed, you should be able to improve performance with multiple threads.  A tutorial on how to do so is way beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use multiple thread to perform [a] single task.

That depends on what you mean by "task." Your example shows a single function that performs a single computation when it is called by a thread. (Note: It's not a very interesting computation, but it's a computation none the less.)  If that same function is called by more than one thread, then all that will happen is, each thread will perform the identical computation because that's the only thing that your function was written to do. No time will be saved.

In order for multiple threads to cooperate on solving some problem, *You* have to write the code that instructs them to cooperate. *You* have to write one or more functions that can perform *parts* of the computation; *You* have to write code that assigns the different parts to the different threads; and *You* likely will need to write code that combines the partial results into a single, final result. There is no magic in Java that will automatically re-write your single-threaded code to do those things for you. You have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A sample snippet using parallel streams

```
final String[] value = {"a"};
    Stream.iterate(1,x -> x+1 )
            .limit(10)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(y -> value[0] = value[0] + "b"  );
```

You can change the limit value to the number you require. On my machine with parallel i see 5x performance gain with parallel when limit is 100000.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem please mark it as the answer or consider up voting @RenceAbi